# How do I remove a node from a linked list?

Tags: python, class, oop, error-handling, linked-list

As a first project on OOP I'm  working on a linked list oop class, got most of the methods done but the remove node method is not working. 
When I run the code I get this error:

AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'val'

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in it!

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.next = None


class Linked_list():
    def __init__(self):
        self.next = None
        nextnode=self.next


    def insert(self, val, loc):
        p = self
        for i in range(0, loc):
            p = p.next
        tmp = p.next
        newNode = Node(val)
        p.next = newNode
        newNode.next = tmp

    def find(self, val):
        p = self.next
        # loc = 0     # in case we want to return the location
        while p != None:
            if p.value == val:
                return p
            else:
                p = p.next
                #loc=loc+1   # in case we want to return the location
        return None

    def remove_node(self, node):
        current = self.next
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
                if current.val == node:
                    found = True
                else:
                    previous = current
                    current = current.next

        if previous == None:
            self.next = current.next
        else:
            previous.current.next



    def __eq__(self, other):
        cnt=0
        s=self.next
        p=other.next
        if Linked_list.length(self)!=Linked_list.length(other):
            return False
        if s.value==p.value:
            for i in range(Linked_list.length(self)-1):
                p=p.next
                s=s.next
                if s.value==p.value:
                    cnt+=1
        if cnt==Linked_list.length(self)-1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Node` class has an attribute `value` assigned in the `__init__` method, but not an attribute `val`, hence the error. The confusion probably comes from the fact that the variable you pass to `__init__` is called `val`.